# How to fix npm update error? (# npm install )

Tags: npm

**strong text**
when i run this command line: npm install -g firebase-tool
it shows this error...
how to fix it.. I am suffering ...

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/firebase-tool - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'firebase-tool@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/azam/.npm/_logs/2022-10-03T12_42_10_994Z-debug-0.log

Comment: try  ``` npm install -g firebase-tool --force```

Answer (score 0):

It's telling your you are trying to install a package that doesn't exist, I cannot find any package called functions-helper, did you mean `firebase-functions-helper`